# Multiple REPLACE in SQL

Tags: sql, replace

I would like to create a "view" table where I would like to rename 2 rows (2 different names).
Unfortunately, when I type this command, it doesn't work:

```
SELECT torch_cooling AS MASTER,
       REPLACE (REPLACE(torch_cooling, 'gas', 'Gasgekühlt')'water', 'Wassergekühlt') AS TEXT
FROM to_torches
```

I would like "gas" to be "Gasgekühlt" and "Water" to be "Wassergekühlt".

[image]

```
SELECT torch_cooling AS MASTER,
       REPLACE (REPLACE(torch_cooling, 'gas', 'Gasgekühlt') 'water', 'Wassergekühlt') AS TEXT
FROM to_torches`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `REPLACE` is not the right tool for this, consider using a `CASE` for this.

```sql
SELECT torch_cooling AS MASTER, 
       CASE torch_cooling 
            WHEN 'gas'   THEN 'Gasgekühlt'
            WHEN 'water' THEN 'Wassergekühlt'
       END AS TEXT
  FROM t;
```

This is not really scalable, if you want to scale this, you should use a mapping table.

Comment: You are super! thanks for the help. It will be absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the option to use a `CASE WHEN` construct for that (which is absolutely fine), you can also use a function like `DECODE`. Usually, your DB provides such a function.

The example according to your situation:

```
SELECT torch_cooling AS master, 
DECODE (torch_cooling ,'gas','Gasgekühlt', 'water','Wassergekühlt') AS text 
FROM to_torches;
```

Please note the exact syntax and function name for this way depend on your DB type since the function name differs.

`DECODE` will be used in Oracle DB's, but there are similar functions in other DB types, too.